# how to keep order of data in list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list

I have a dropdown with checkboxes in it. Lets say I've the following data displayed in the dropdown:

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="Products" id="Products">
    <option value="1">A</option>
    <option value="2">B</option>
    <option value="3">C</option>
    <option value="4">D</option>
</select>
```

Then I checked record no 4, 2, 3 and submit the page. In the controller I change the `int[] arrIDs` into `List<int> listIDs` to collect the Products from the database.

```
List<Product> products = db.Product
    .Where(d => listIDs.Contains(d.ProductID))
    .ToList();
```

But I've got the `products` is sorted in the following sequence 2, 3, 4. I want to keep the sequence based on the records that I've selected in the page 4, 2, 3. How to solve it?

Comment: By *"order"* do you mean *"the sequence in which products were selected in the UI"* ?

Comment: @ArghyaC yes, you're right

Comment: Do you have the correct sequence in your `List<int> listIDs`?

Comment: How do you know that the user first selected 4, then 2 and finally 3?

Comment: @TimSchmelter, on the event onChange, I find the value of selected item and move it into array. This array that will be sent to the controller. I've checked in the controller the sequence is correct 4, 2, 3

Comment: @ArghyaC what do you mean "the correct sequence in your `List<int> listIDs`"? `listIDs` contains the product ids which selected by user in the UI. It's on the following sequence 4, 2, 3

Comment: Was asking if the sequence/order is correct in listIDs. You already answered yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`List.IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the index for the order:

```
List<Product> products = db.Product
    .Where(d => listIDs.Contains(d.ProductID))
    .AsEnumerable()
    .OrderBy(d => listIDs.IndexOf(d.ProductID))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

The multiple select box does not preserve the order of clicks.

You'll need to use Javascript to watch the clicks, and record the order into a hidden field, which will be submitted with the form.  Or give up on the multiple select box, and use a component like [this one](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=pickList&skin=blueSky).  (That's not a .NET component, but I suspect that similar ones exist.)

Comment: He's already taking care of that, but not mentioned in question properly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a `GroupJoin`:

```
List<Product> products = listIDs
    .GroupJoin(
        db.Product,
        x => x,
        y => y.ProductID,
        (x, ys) => ys.First())
    .ToList();
```

This performs the equivalent of a "left outer join", which maintains the values of `listIDs` in their original order, then matches each `listID` with the corresponding product in the table.

Note: this code assumes there is always a single matching `ProductID` in the database.